# Excel VBA - export multiple sheets into PDF with different combinations and names

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, export

Please help me - new job and I am out of my depth with this one.
So I have 8 tabs that need to be exported into PDF in a certain order and need to be named certainly.

Tab 1 - page 1 of version 1 - Client X
Tab 2 - page 2 and 3 of version 1 - Client X
Tab 3 - page 1 of version 2 - Client X
Tab 4 - page 2 and 3 of version 2 - Client X
Tab 5 - page 1 of version 1 - Client Y
Tab 6 - page 2 and 3 of version 1 - Client Y
Tab 7 - page 1 of version 2 - Client Y
Tab 8 - page 2 and 3 of version 2 - Client Y

The outputs - 4 pdfs:
Client X - version 1
Client X - version 2
Client Y - version 1
Client Y - version 2

The only way I can figure out is by writing 4 private macros and adding them together into one. The problem is that I will have 15 clients and I don't want to do 15 subs (I think it might slow down my excel). So I know we can create a loop that will look at cell values with names of the tabs etc but I am failing at that and it's been days now.
Please help!

So my duplicate subs all look like that:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ClientXversion1()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Fname As String
Dim i As Integer

Sheets(Array("Tab1Name", "Tab2Name")).Select
Sheets("Tab1Name").Activate
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"O:\Regular Reporting\PDFs\Client X version1.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

So I duplicated sub for all versions and clients and put them all under main sub:

```
Sub Main() 
    ClientXVersion1
    ClientXVersion2
    etc

End Sub
```

As you can see it doesn't make sense to have so many duplicate subs when we can do a loop and using cell value in a parametres sheet.

By the way, I tried other way without activating the sheets and the export result is not in correct format (ignores print areas, even though I explicitly set not to ignore them).

Anyway, any ideas?

Comment: Write the 15 subs for 15 clients, the cut and paste monkey is your friend. If you have been working on this for days then you could have completed the task by now. Keep it simple and you may discover how to improve the code as you write it.

Comment: Welcome user23526950! Read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!